# Nothing happens when sending int values from one class to another iOS

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, xcode7

Im trying to send 2 int values from one class to another but the values never appear in the new class.

I.e. Im trying to sending them from

level.m

```
#import "GameScene.h"

@class GameScene;

@interface Level ()

@property (strong, nonatomic) GameScene *gamescene;

-(void)BlankPositionAtColumn:(int) blankY row:(int)blankX{
NSLog(@"BlankPositionAtColumn: BlankX, BlankY: %d, %d", blankX, blankY);

[self.gamescene BlankPosition:blankY row:blankX];}
```

to

gamescene.m

```
- (void)BlankPosition:(int) blankPY row:(int)blankPX{
NSLog(@"Gamescene --> BlankPosition:(int) blankPY row:(int)blankPX %d, %d", blankPY, blankPX);}
```

but nothing happens.

what am I missing?

Comment: Is `self.gamescene` nil by any chance?

Comment: I´m not sure... don´t think so :S

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this line to level.m before calling the method in gamescene.m:

```
self.gamescene = [[GameScene alloc] init];
```

Comment: @Chris79 I'm glad I could help. +1 and answer would be appreciated.

Comment: I do not have enough reputation to be able to set it to +1 :(